# Develop Solution/Web Parts/Apps for SharePoint 2013 in Visual Studio 2012 (From Local Machine)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have SharePoint Foundation 2013 installed in the windows server 2012.

Is it possible to develop SharePoint solution/web parts/Apps using Visual Studio 2012 in my local machine(Windows 7 64Bit) without having SharePoint installed in local machine?

if i need to develop SharePoint solution/web parts/Apps in visual studio 2012, do i need to install visual studio in the Server that contain share point Foundation 2013?

Cant i develop in local machine and deploy it to server?

Can someone help me on this issue? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

• How to Perform SharePoint Development On A Client Workstation
15 Feb 2011 by Bryant Sombke in Guides, Web, Windows 16 Comments 
One of the most difficult restrictions for a SharePoint developer to deal with can be the requirement to do development on a SharePoint server.  Personally, I prefer doing my development on my local machine, eliminating the need to establish a remote desktop connection to a different machine in order to write code.
Unfortunately, SharePoint development requires many DLL files which are included with an installation of SharePoint on a server.  To make matters worse, SharePoint 2010 requires an x64 server, further complicating the issue.  Fortunately, there is an easy workaround that can allow a SharePoint developer to be productive, even while using their laptop on the road without an available internet connection.
Copy the SharePoint DLLs
As I mentioned before, SharePoint development requires DLL files that are included with a SharePoint 2007 or 2010 installation.  The first step is to grab these off of a SharePoint server.  For SharePoint 2007, they are located in the hive at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\ISAPI\`, and for 2010 at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAP\`.  Copy the DLL files in this directory from the server, and paste them at the exact same file path on your local machine.  Since your PC likely does not have SharePoint installed, you may have to create the directory structure yourself.

SharePoint 2007 DLL Directory
Register the Assemblies to the GAC
Now that you have the DLL files on your workstation, you will be able to include them as references in your Visual Studio projects just as you would with any other DLLs.  However, if you want them to auto-register with your project when you use a Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint template or a WSPBuilder template, you must register the DLL files in your local Global Assembly Cache.  To do this, open the directory on your workstation that contains the SharePoint DLLs and drag them into the C:\Windows\assembly\ directory.  This will register them with the GAC on your workstation, and Visual Studio should successfully find the assemblies when a template is loaded up.  Although these assemblies may be 64-bit, this will work fine even though your workstation may be 32-bit.

Global Assembly Cache
If you’ve successfully completed the two steps above, you should be able to write your code and successfully compile your project.  Once you generate your WSP file, you can then deploy it like any other WSP.
Please Use Caution
If you do development for both 2007 and 2010, you can do this for both on the same workstation; just be sure to complete both steps for each version.  Since the 2007 and 2010 assemblies have different Assembly Versions (12.0.0.0 and 14.0.0.0), you don’t have to worry about conflicts in the GAC.  Be sure to use caution, however, because in my experience, Visual Studio tends to grab the SharePoint 2010 version of the DLL even for a SharePoint 2007 project if they’re both registered on your workstation.  If this happens, remove the incorrect reference, and add a reference to the correct 2007 DLL from your 12\ISAPI directory.

From http://www.techerator.com/2011/02/how-to-perform-sharepoint-development-on-a-client-workstation/

Answer (score 0):

You can develop SharePoint Apps from anywhere -- this is even more convenient when you're using the SharePoint 2013 development site template to do your testing on.

For farm/sandbox solutions things get more complicated...
If you want to develop webparts or other farm/sandbox solutions you need to have visual studio and sharepoint installed on the same machine (visual studio depends on the sharepoint dlls to build and debug properly). You also need to run Visual Studio as an admin for this scenario (so you'll need to be a local administrator for the machine in question).

It's possible to run SharePoint 2010 on Windows7, but this is not supported by SharePoint 2013 -- you'll have to run Windows Server for the development machine.

You can move your files from a development environment to your production SharePoint farm by building a WSP file for your farm solution on the development machine then sending it to your farm admin who can then deploy it to the production sharepoint environment... For a sandbox solution the site collection admin can add the solution file (WSP) to the site collection 'solution gallery' then active it (for more info on sandbox solution installation see the msdn documentation here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615450(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615450%28v=office.14%29.aspx))

Hope that summary helps, for more info on setting up development environments see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definately develop SharePoint solutions from your local machine where you dont have SharePoint installed.
For doing this you need to follow some steps -

Go to the server where SharePoint 2013 is installed and follow steps from 1 to 3

1. Go to Run and type "regedit"
2. Navigate towards HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office
3. Right click on 15.0 and click Export. Save the exported file

Now go to your machine where sharepoint is not installed and follow below steps:

1. Now open Registry on your machine
2. Import the 15 directory which was exported from SharePoint server
3. Open Powershell
4. Run this command

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\web server extensions\15.0\" -Name "Location" -Value "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\"

Now open visual studio 2013 and you will be able to create SharePoint 2013 project without error.